# how to select all items in zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh

in bash, we can say

```
dnf install <some-pkg>-*
```

or

```
rm -rf *.jpg
```

but when I'm using zsh, it doesn't do anything with the star (*) character!
how can I do those commands on zsh?!

Comment: It works for me. At least the second example, I'm pretty sure. Try pressing tab twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two different uses of globs. With `dnf`, you expect `dnf` itself to expand the pattern against the available packages. With `rm`, you are expecting the *shell* to expand the pattern against the files in the current directory and passing the resulting names to `rm`.

In `bash`, the default behavior is for a pattern that doesn't match anything to be treated as a literal string. That's why the `dnf` example works in `bash`: when there are no local files matching `<some-pkg>-*`, the literal string is passed to `zsh`.

The solution is to quote strings that you intended to be treated literally, instead of relying on your shell's treatment of unmatched patterns. The following will work as intended in both shells:

```
dnf install "<some-pkg>.*"
rm -rf *.jpg
```

In both shells, you can change how unmatched patterns are treated. To make `zsh` act like the `bash` default, use

```
setopt NO_NOMATCH
```

To make `bash` behave like the `zsh` default, you could use

```
shopt -s failglob
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the globbing is disabled on your zsh. Enable it using the below command in zsh:

```
setopt GLOB
```